# Making a table in python such that all numbers with the same output are in column 2 and the output is in column 1

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a table such that the first column is the integers x from 1 to n, and the second column is all numbers y such that f(y) = x. Essentially I am looking to construct a table with the preimages of a number in the column next to said number.

---

If it is not obvious already I am not a coder! Any help would be much appreciated, and sorry if this has been asked elsewhere.

---

I will add more info to be clearer! Is there a way to do the following - construct the first column to be from 0 to n. Calculate first f(1) and if f(1) = 0 then put 1 in the row of 0. Then continue by calculating f(x) and if f(x) = y putting x in the row of y. If later on there is an x' which also satisfies f(x') = y then adding x' next to x in the row of y.

---

I hope this is clear enough!

Comment: Do you have a specific function in mind?

Comment: I am doing this for aliquot sequences, so the function is the restricted divisor function - but any example is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use squaring as a simple placeholder function.

Hopefully this answers your question. For this example, I'll pretend we don't know how to find a number's square root, and use the square function to try and find it. In this example, the index of the row itself will represent the y value.

```
def square(x):
    return x * x


square_root_table = [[] for i in range(100)]


for i in range(-100, 100):
    answer = square(i)
    if answer < len(square_root_table):
        square_root_table[answer].append(i)
```

To print the table, iterate over each row and print it along with its index.

```
for index, row in enumerate(square_root_table):
    print(f'{index}: {row}')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but using your squaring example I would want eg 4 in the first column and then 2, -2 in the second column. I'm sorry if my question was badly worded!

Comment: Oh, I didn't read it closely enough. I'm not familiar with aliquot sequences. Is there a function that simply does the inverse? For example, with the squaring example, you could just switch out a squaring function with a square root one.

Comment: There isn't, which is why I'm trying to do this - to see if there's a pattern !! Is there a way like the append function to add something to a row?

Comment: Is that more in line with your question?

Comment: thank you that's amazing. is there a way to keep the first number of each row separate from the others?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from pynverse import inversefunc
# please replace 5 with n
a = list(range(1,5))
# here f(x) is i square, it gives the right results
y = list(inversefunc(lambda x: x**2, i) for i in a)
# zip function helps in mapping two lists with respect to their indexes
print(pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, y)), columns=['a', 'y']))
```

my output

```
    a                   y
 0  1                 1.0
 1  2  1.4142135544525607
 2  3  1.7320508072682492
 3  4  2.0000000017714545
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is unclear - but using your squaring example I would be looking for the row of 4 for example to be 4 in the first column and then 2, -2 in the second column?

Comment: yes i understood your question, we need to find inverse function,  that is `y=inversef(x)`, then in place of `i**2` replace the function , i will check into and post the answer with some detail

Comment: the function I am looking at has no inverse

Comment: i have changed my answer, i mean python creates the inverse for the function, just replace the square function there with yours